# Поиск по вложенному объекту JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Исходный массив]

Имеется массив объектов (скриншот выше), нужно выполнить поиск по id внутри cards и вывести новый массив как на скриншоте ниже (поиск по id 6,7,11,12,13)

[image: Пример вывода]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать что-то подобное?

Пример вывода:

```
const data = [{
  did: 0,
  name: "Название",
  cards: [
    { id: 6, title: "Карточка 6", type: "card" },
    { id: 7, title: "Карточка 7", type: "card" }
  ]
}, {
  did: 1,
  name: "Название 2",
  cards: [
    { id: 11, title: "Карточка 11", type: "card" }
  ]
}, {
  did: 2,
  name: "Название 3",
  cards: [
    { id: 12, title: "Карточка 12", type: "card" },
    { id: 13, title: "Карточка 13", type: "card" }
  ]
}];
```

Comment: Напечатайте код текстом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  did: 0,
  name: "Название",
  cards: [
    { id: 6, title: "Карточка 6", type: "card" },
    { id: 7, title: "Карточка 7", type: "card" }
  ]
}, {
  did: 1,
  name: "Название 2",
  cards: [
    { id: 11, title: "Карточка 11", type: "card" }
  ]
}, {
  did: 2,
  name: "Название 3",
  cards: [
    { id: 12, title: "Карточка 12", type: "card" },
    { id: 13, title: "Карточка 13", type: "card" }
  ]
}];

var ids = new Set([6, 7, 12]);

var res = data
  .map(x => ({ ...x, cards: x.cards.filter(c => ids.has(c.id)) }))
  .filter(x => x.cards.length)

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```